# What is the C++ Equivalent of FindPlayerStart in Unreal Engine Blueprints

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

What is the C++ Equivalent of FindPlayerStart in Unreal Engine Blueprints?

The function on GameModeBase is not virtual; even though it can be overridden in blueprints.

Lots of older examples from around 4.3 seem to suggest there is a FindPlayerStart_Implementation function but I can't find it in 4.19.

How can I achieve the same behavior as overriding FindPlayerStart and returning my own PlayerStart Actor in a blueprint?

Comment: I didn't work with Unreal before, but I found [this](http://api.unrealengine.com/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AGameModeBase/FindPlayerStart/index.html). Does this help? You can find detailed information about `AActor`, `AController`, `FString` by clicking on hyperlinks.

Comment: This is the method I found above and have previously used in blueprints. Blueprints allow it to be overridden but it's not virtual in C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer via a kind Unreal Engine Forums Promoter: [here](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/1473046-what-is-the-c-equivilent-of-findplayerstart-in-unreal-engine-blueprints)

Answer (score 0):

The 'override' in Blueprint is actually a blueprint event which is published by the base C++ class.

```
 UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent, Category="Game")
 class AActor* FindPlayerStart( AController* Player, const FString& IncomingName = TEXT("") );
```

So, you don't subclass and extend directly in C++.

If you want to tweak the behavior in C++ code, implement a Blueprint function in your game mode class -- a `UFUNCTION` marked as `BlueprintPure` so you can add it to the blueprint as a node.

```
// .h
UFUNCTION(BlueprintPure, Category=Game, meta=(DisplayName="CustomPlayerStart"))
AActor* CustomPlayerStartLogic(AController* Player);


// .cpp
AActor* MyCustomGameMode::CustomPlayerStartLogic(AController* Player)
{
 /// your logic here
 return ThePlayerActor;
}
```

Then use that new node in your game mode blueprint in the override of the game mode's FindPlayerStart "function"  -- as long as it returns an `AActor*` you can pass that to the return node of the blueprint override. I didn't bother taking the string input from the overridden function in this example, but if your logic required it you could add a `const FString&` argument to the function and wire it to the original node.

See [this UnrealEngine.com post](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/503148/findplayerstart-incoming-name-parameter-cant-be-sp.html)